# Определение типа файла по сигнатуре

Tags: c#, файлы

Всем привет! Подскажите как определить тип файла по сигнатуре? Есть массив байт, который я сохраняю в файл. Нужно определить тип и присвоить расширение этому файлу.

Comment: первая ссылка в гугле: 

http://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html

Answer (score 1):

Можно определить какие-то конкретные типы файлов, но никак не все т.к. нет единого формата контейнеров файлов.

Comment: http://www.gcmsite.ru/?pg=art&id=delphi-file-type
вот функция на делфях
нужно что то типа этого??